# Can a linux user access to a file in this case?

Tags: linux, root, non-root-user, privileges, access-control

This is a theoretical question. I'm using a linux system with two users: `root` and `nonRoot`. I'm debugging an application as nonRoot, that uses a file placed in the following path:

`/home/nonRootFolder/fileUsed.xml`

If I execute `ls -las` command in home directory, I see:

```
 0 drw-------    4 root     root           496 Oct  3 21:45 ./
 0 drwxr-xr-x    4 root     root           688 Oct  3 21:45 ../
     ...
 0 drwxr-x---    2 nonRoot  nonRoot        432 Oct  3 21:45 nonRootFolder/ 
     ...
```

The same command in `/` directory shows the next output:

```
 0 drw-------    4 root     root           496 Oct  3 21:45 ./
 0 drwxr-xr-x    4 root     root           688 Oct  3 21:45 ../
     ...
 0 drwxr-x---    4 root     root           688 Oct  3 21:45 home/
     ...
```

So, the application is executed by `nonRoot` and uses a file in `nonRootFolder`. However, this file and folder is placed `home` with `root` as proprietary and `nonRoot` has not root privileges in the system.

Can the application use the file in this case?

Comment: `getfacl` might be more clear. It depends on what path is the program accessing, it doesn't have to go through /home.

Comment: Actually I think the system is going to be hosed. Since even root doesn't even have execute permission on `/`, so root can't use any file within it either. Of course root have the permission to change folder permission back to a sane value, but since `/usr/bin/chmod` is under `/`, recovery will be tricky unless you boot to another system.

Answer (score 1):

User `nonRoot` cannot access `/home/nonRootFolder` because the permissions on `/home` do not allow that user to traverse (`x`) into it.  You would need at least `o+x` on `/home`.

Here, I'm assuming that `nonRoot` does not belong to the `root` group; I wouldn't suggest adding a non-root user to the `root` group.

Comment: What if `nonRoot` belongs to the `root` group?

Comment: @RudiC Still doesn't help you since group permissions are set to no access.